# RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and want to send email but I'm getting this error:

```
RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

How could I solve this?
My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=oEontENjBIdIrzaXhk9v9Q
```

My function in controller:

```
public function mailContact(ContactRequest $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $body = $request->input('body');
    $sent = Mail::send('emails.contact', compact('name', 'email', 'body'), function ($message) {
        $message->to('khudadadrs@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Message');
    });

    if ($sent) {
        return Redirect::back()->withMessage('تشکر از اینکه تماس گرفتید.');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withError('متاسفانه ایمیل ارسال نشد.دوباره تلاش کنید');
}
```

Comment: Your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` should be `tls` and you should ensure that the Mailgun settings under `config/services` are configured correctly. Also, have you installed `Guzzle` to handle the request?

Comment: Yea I just run this command to be download: composer require guzzle/... and it installed, is there any additional settings

Comment: So to confirm, have you tried using this with `Guzzle` installed correctly?

Comment: If you follow this part of the post exactly, you should be able to configure Mailgun correctly http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-email-mailgun

Comment: service:  'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

Comment: Based on your `.env` above, you haven't set a field called `MAILGUN_SECRET`

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_SECRET=oEontENjBIdIrzaXhk9v9Q     still same error

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download
2. Extract it an place it in `..\php\ext` (curl.cainfo="E:\xampp\php\ext)"
3. Open the php.ini and write after the `php_curl.dll`: `curl.cainfo="..\php\ext\cacert.pem"(curl.cainfo="E:\xampp\php\ext\cacert.pem")`
4. Restart the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I added the cacert.pem file as described in http://codeontrack.com/solve-laravelxamppguzzlehttp-curl-error-60-no-sll-certificate/
but now I'm getting this error:

> RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
>   cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: [pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem
>   CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Any help?